# Join a partially matched table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, left-join, inner-join

Good morning,

I'd like to join two tables, but the 'name' column doesn't fully match in some cases.

Example in T1 the name is 'Acosta, Joan' but in T2 the name is 'Perez Acosta, Joan' or 'Acosta, Manuel Joan'.

The main reason that I'd like to join these tables is to update a field that is in T1.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: You *might* be able to use something like `SOUNDEX`, but the real problem is the data; and from a data perspective `'Acosta, Joan'` and `'Perez Acosta, Joan'` are *not* the same name. Really, names aren't a good unique identifier (take this from someone who knew someone else who not only shared a name with someone else I knew, but also their DoB *and* we lived in the same street).

Comment: If you want to relate tables consistently, you should tackle the task of fixing the relation first. Otherwise, any update you perform based on fuzzy matches may end up corrupting the data more than it already is.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard way to join if you need to perform a check on fields with different (but similar) values.

What you can do is define a function taking as parameters the two values to compare and returning the distance between the two fields. Then you can use that function in the join, with something like

```
   SELECT *
   FROM T1
   INNER JOIN T2 ON distance(T1.NAME, T2.NAME) < MAX_DISTANCE_ALLOWED
```

How to code the confidence function is how of scope, but you can for example use a variant of the [Levensthein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance):

> In information theory, linguistics, and computer science, the Levenshtein distance is a string metric for measuring the difference between two sequences. Informally, the Levenshtein distance between two words is the minimum number of single-character edits (insertions, deletions or substitutions) required to change one word into the other.